# Probabilities of mutations in telomeres?

Tags: mutations, telomere

Frankly I am a programmer, I've been looking at sites like NCBI and others, but couldn't find what I was looking for so if someone can help:

Can you give me the probabilities of

1. mutations in Saccharomyces Cerevisiae's telomeres.
2. Probability of having an insertion
3. Probability of having a deletion.
4. Probability of having a substitution.

The reason I need this is that I want to generate true-telomeric data based on, the telomere structure consensus.